# Sort String Alphabetically Regardless of Capitalization - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, ascii, alphabetical-sort, alphabetized

Working on [this codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/alphabetized/train/javascript).

> Re-order the characters of a string, so that they are concatenated into a new string in "case-insensitively-alphabetical-order-of-appearance" order. Whitespace and punctuation shall simply be removed!
>
> The input is restricted to contain no numerals and only words containing the english alphabet letters.
>
> Example:
>
> alphabetized("The Holy Bible") // "BbeehHilloTy"

I started with:

```js
function alphabetized(s) {
    s = s.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
    return s.split("").sort().join("");
}

console.log(alphabetized("The Holy Bible"));
```

But of course we want to return `BbeehHilloTy`, maintaining capitalization of the original characters.

Frankly I'm not understanding why the desired outcome should be `BbeehHilloTy`.

If we're not sorting according to the ASCII character code values, then what determines whether or not a capital letter should appear in front of a lowercase letter in the new string?

Comment: The order of appearance in the original string, as you state

Comment: so write a custom sort function....

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) "The default sort order is built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values" Note: **NOT** ASCII table values.

Comment: `s.split("").sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase())).join("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that creates a stable sort by comparing the characters' indexes in the string if they are equal:

```js
function alphabetized(s){
  s = s.replace(/\s+|\W+|\d+|[_]+/g, "");
  return s.split('')
    .map(function(x, i){ return [x, i]; })
    .sort(function([a, i], [b, j]){
      a = a.toLowerCase();
      b = b.toLowerCase();
      if (a == b)
        return i - j;
      else if (a < b)
        return -1;
      else
        return 1;
      })
      .map(function([x, i]){ return x; })
      .join('');
}

console.log(alphabetized("The Holy Bible"));
```

Comment: I am realizing that according to the challenge, it needs to take random strings into account as well - should handle non-alphabetical characters.

Answer (score 0):

According to @user3483203's code:

```js
function alphabetized(s) {
    s = s.replace(/\s+|\W+|\d+|[_]+/g, "");
    return s.split("").sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase())).join("");
}

console.log(alphabetized("The Holy Bible"));
```

So the key is to use [localCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) here.

**EDIT**: Actually this solution doesn't work for all tests on Codewars.